# No built in audio in pipewire after HDMI unplugged

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, pipewire

System information:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Pipewire (previously PulseAudio, but similar issue persisted)
- [Audio Output Switcher Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/751/audio-output-switcher/)

After I unplug the HDMI cable off the notebook, the audio doesn't switch back to built-in. I specifically moved from PulseAudio to PipeWire in hope, that this would be fixed (because something simmilar was happening with PA), but it did not help, although with PipeWire it is at least as simple as going to sound settings in gnome, after which it fixes itself. With PA I never discovered what sequence of actions actually fix the issue.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that or how to further investigate? I'm not an expert in the Linux's audio stack...

What I do:

1. Plug in HDMI
2. Select the HDMI audio output using extension menu

   > [image]
3. Unplug HDMI ­now the "Speakers - Built-in Audio" disappears

   > [image]

To fix this I go to gnome sound settings and on the drop down list select (now present and only) missing "Speakers -Built-in Audio"

> [image]

After that, the controls for the audio devices appear.

> [image]

Comment: What you'd want is try latest Pipewire, and then report a bug if it's still reproducible. The only real problem here is: I'm not sure how it's best to execute in your case. You see, switching between outputs in PW is handled by "session manager". There're two of them: `media-session` and `wireplumber`. There's [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pipewire-debian/+archive/ubuntu/pipewire-upstream) with latest PW, but it doesn't provide `wireplumber`, whereas `media-session` isn't actively developed. If you're comfortable compiling PW yourself, you could test upstream `wireplumber`.

Comment: FTR, here's [an upstream link to a wireplumber](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/wireplumber). You could test if PW exhibits the problem with it, then report a bug if it does. PW is an actively developed project, so there's a high chance it will get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Hi-Angel, I followed the [guide for switching to wireplumber and pipewire using upstream PPA's](https://pipewire-debian.github.io/pipewire-debian/#add-the-launchpad-ppa) and the problem doesn't seem to occur anymore — HDMI. This upgraded me from the <del>pipewire</del> wireplumber `0.4.8-4` to `0.4.11.r31.g8fa1693-1~ubuntu22.04` (also upgraded pipewire from 0.3.48 to 0.3.60).

Also it is worth noting, for anyone wondering, that [the module for automatically switching audio output should be enabled](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Sound_does_not_automatically_switch_when_connecting_a_new_device).

Comment: You probably meant "this upgraded wireplumber" not "… pipewire". PW itself has different release numbers